# Watching for form data in nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

On my page I have a form,

```
<div v-if="this.userdata.address == ''">Please enter your address</div>

Your address
<input type="text" v-model="userdata.address">
Your phone
<input type="text" v-model="userdata.phone">
Your message
<input type="text" :disabled="this.userdata.address == '' ? true : false">
```

And my script section is:

```
<script>
export default {
   data() {
     return {
      userdata: {
        companydata: {}
      }
     }
   }
}

.....
<script>
```

If my user is Authorized, "userdata" data will be filled in fetch().

My problem is to check, if address field filled in or not on the go, and then if user entered his address, make Message field active, but if he not filled it, or cleaned this field (if he authorized and data was loaded to form in fetch() method), make Message field disabled again.

Problem is that if I reload this page, everything is works, but if I navigate to it from other page, nothing is works.

Whats a problem can be?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the address data in my `userdata`. I managed to fix my problem simply by adding it as an empty string.

```
<script>
export default {
   data() {
     return {
      userdata: {
        address: "", //// Adding this solved my problem
        companydata: {}
      }
     }
   }
}

.....
<script>
```